# AngularJS - Binding/Replacing AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to load AJAX content and using ng-repeat to create a list of items. On the content I also have {{noun}} as a placeholder. My assumption was that when the ajax content is loaded, AngularJS would automatically replace {{noun}} with the data from $scope.noun model. But it isn't the case. Any quick and dirty way to make it happen?

Here's my code:

```
AllControllers.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.noun = "My Noun";

    $scope.headlines = [{
        headline: "Top 10 Tricks to {{noun}}",
        usage: 10,
        votes: 100
    }];

    $scope.load_headlines = function() {
        $http.get('/data/headlines.json').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.headlines = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(status);
            });
    };
    }]);

<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="load_headlines()">

    <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="headline in headlines">
    <tr>
        <td>{{headline.headline}}</td>
        <td class="center">{{headline.usage}}</td>
        <td class="center">{{headline.votes}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the Ajax code you are talking about?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to include the ajax call. Because at the end of the day the $scope.headlines will be an array of objects. And the attribute headline will have the placeholder {{noun}}. So, how you populate $scope.headlines may not be relevant.

Comment: Where is `headlines_displayed` coming from?

Comment: Does it work when you omit the `load_headlines` method and just use the fixed version of `$scope.headlines`?

Comment: Good catch. That was a typo, should be headlines. Still, no change to {{noun}} when the headline attribute is rendered.

Comment: @roosevelt. `{{noun}}` only works in view and not controller. Also, it won't matter as you are completely replacing the `headlines` array with your new `data`.

Comment: roosevelt  my answer hekp you?

Answer (score 1):

you can binding the {{moon}} in the td repeated.

change the code like this:

```
AllControllers.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.noun = "My Noun";

    $scope.headlines = [{
        headline: "Top 10 Tricks to ",
        usage: 10,
        votes: 100
    }];
}]);

<tbody ng-repeat="headline in headlines_displayed">
<tr>
    <td>{{headline.headline}} {{noun}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{headline.usage}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{headline.votes}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That won't work. Because I'm populating $scope.headlines using an ajax call. The $scope.headlines is dynamic.

Comment: i update my answer, you can binding tow params in html;

Answer (score 1):

Your $scope variable is differently to the ngRepeat variable.
I think you have to change the $scope variable in your controller:

```
$scope.headlines_displayed = [{
        headline: "Top 10 Tricks to "+$scope.noun,
        usage: 10,
        votes: 100
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Ended up doing this:

```
<td>{{headline.headline.replace("{{noun\}\}", noun)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $interpolate service to compile the string before assigning it to the scope. Passing a string with {{}} will not work. In your http success callback do something like this. This will replace your {{noun}} with scope value.

```
 $scope.load_headlines = function() {
    $http.get('/data/headlines.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.headlines = data;
            $interpolate($scope.headlines.headline)($scope);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(status);
        });
};
}]);
```

Take a look at the the this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmzbph8d/)